# How to configure rest template in Spring MVC 4?

Tags: java, spring, rest, resttemplate

How to configure RestTemplate in Spring MVC 4 using namespace configuration/xml configuration with basic http host.

Comment: Have you tried the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc)? Your question is way too general.

Comment: @Jeyp, Yup I already did. looking for something that uses the http host so I would not configure the scheme,url and host of the web service

Comment: What do you want to do? You want to perform a HTTP POST request? Or you want to build a web-application that accepts a HTTP POST?

Comment: I want to send http post and http get to a server

Comment: I posted an example for requests with RestTemplate.

Comment: @Jeyp using xml configuration.

Comment: Well you dont need any configuration if you want to SEND post and get requests. If you want to RECEIVE them in a server. Then you have to set up a web service using Spring MVC, which is a totally different thing. [Here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc) is a link to the docs.

Answer (score 1):

Using RestTemplate class is very easy. [Here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html) is a good overview.

```
RestTemplate rest = new RestTemplate();
String response;

response = rest.getForObject("http://www.google.com", String.class);

Object postData = null;
response = rest.postForObject("http://yourdomain.com/example", postData, String.class);
```

Comment: Here are a few [good examples for using RestTemplate.postForObject](https://www.codota.com/code/java/methods/org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate/postForObject)